# GitFlow работа с ветками

Tags: git, git-flow

недавно начал познакомился с GitFlow и в связи с этим у меня осталось несколько вопросов, о которых я хотел бы спросить здесь... Допустим мне нужно добавить новый логгер я создаю ветку feature/new-logger делаю туда пару коммитов и затем сливаю в develop, стоит ли мне после слияния удалять эту ветку, либо ее стоит пушить на сервер или оставить локально у себя, либо может вообще ребейсить в develop(тоже самое и с фиксами)? Хотел бы чтобы кто-нибудь описал этот момент поподробнее, как с этим следует поступать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В каждой компании свои правила на этот счёт, вообще ветка должна реализовывать некоторую связную последовательность действий, например реализация нового функционала или исправление какой-либо части продукта.

В описанном вами примере, после того как вы вмёржите ветку `feature/new-logger` в `develop`, так понимаю, в этом месте будет считаться, что вы закончили реализацию функционала логгирования и в таком случае, саму ветку стоит удалить. Однако мёржить при этом стоит без `fast-forward` (`--no-ff` флаг), в противном случае, ветка `develop` просто встанет на голову ветки `feature/new-logger` (будет прямая линия, как будто вы комитили в `develop`) и вы потеряете ответвление.